# Schedule windows command with at

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task

What will be the parameter to schedule a program in Windows with the *at* command to run from
Th-Sa, 3am, on **even days** ?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Windows Server 2008

Comment: Not tempted to use the scheduler?

Comment: IMHO for casual use it is over-engineered, too much panels, too much buttons, too much right-clicks, ... yes I'm a *nix admin. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make a PowerShell script as a "container":

2 options here.

You can specify all the "even dates" and check then in a script if today is in the range Th-Sa.

```
at 03:00 /every:2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30 "myscript.ps1"
```

Or, you check in your script wether or not your day is even...

```
Function check-even ($num) {[bool]!($num%2)}
if(check-even (Get-Date).Day)
{
    Write-Host "Go ahead"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Not today!"
}
```

Changing the `Write-Host`'s with what you want it to do (and maybe removing the else-clause). Save it somewhere and run it Th-Sa at 3am.